# Unable initialize the Matlab dll in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, dll

I'm using Windows 7 x64 with Matlab R2012b x32 and VS2010.

I want to call a Matlab function named `add` in C++. So I convert `add.m` to a dll using the `mcc` command, and add it to my project. But I have got a error after I tried to initialize the dll.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(!addInitialize())    
        cout<<"addInitialize fail!!!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output info:

```
First-chance exception at 0x74c6c42d in MatlabTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MathWorks::mcli18nutil::DeployedException at memory location 0x0029eff0..
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[1100] MatlabTest.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: did you change your platform target any cpu to x86?

Comment: @burakKarasoy Yes, I have done that. And I have tried to change the Matlab version, VS version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I ran `mcc` command with `-C` option, so I need to add the `add.ctf` file to the path where the dll stored before initializing the dll.

I also can run `mcc` command again without `-C` option to generate a new dll. And use the new dll instead of the old one to solve this problem.